# Ruby Regex Return

Tags: ruby, regex, return

This is my code

```
pong = /return/.match(cap.array[0])
if pong == "return"
  puts "Pong"
end
```

`cap.array[0]` is definitely matching `/return/` as you can see when I use `pp`:

```
#<MatchData "return">
```

but for some reason, the `if` statement isn't triggering. Any ideas why it won't match? I tried `==` and `===` thinking it could be a type issue, but no joy.

Comment: What is `cap.array[0]`? Why can't you optimize your code to fit a Q and A site?

Comment: It's an array generated by PcapRub of packets. I didn't think it was necessary to state what it was since I knew it was matching anyways.

Comment: You are putting an extra burden on the reader. You should have simply given a string literal, or write something like `some_string`. That would be much clearer.

Comment: Noted. I'll make sure to do that in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex#match` returns a `MatchData` object. Thus, its comparison to string fails.

```
pong = /return/.match('i shall return this')

# cast it to string
if pong.to_s == "return"

# or do this
# if pong[0] == "return"
    puts "Pong"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Why two time check?? You can do it in simple way like below:

```
if /return/ =~ cap.array[0]
  puts "pong"
end
```

For example:

```
/return/ =~ "Functions return value" #=> 14
/return/ =~ "return" #=> 0
```

In ruby:

```
puts "hello" if 0  #=> hello    # 0 is not false
```

So you can avoid multiple checks